# availWidth not working in mozilla & IE

Tags: javascript

as the menu is becoming too big for lower resolution, im removing the less important buttons....but this is not working in mozilla & IE ?

JavaScript

```
  <script>
        if(screen.availWidth<=1345)
        {var r1=document.getElementById("rem1"); r1.remove();}

        if(screen.availWidth<=1255)
        {var r2=document.getElementById("rem2"); r2.remove();}
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<li id='rem1'><a href=''id='pad2'>Resources</a></li>
<li id='rem2'><a href='' id='pad2'>Help</a></li>
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine in those browsers (latest Firefox and IE10). Are you trying to resize and you see that it doesn't remove any elements?

Comment: but not working on 19.0.2 for me....yup..i changed the resolution itself....its working for chrome but not for mozilla & IE....how to make it happen ?

Comment: You can try `window.screen.availWidth`.

Comment: this worked in mozilla but Not on IE ?

Comment: According to there own documentation `screen.availWidth` should work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533488(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: agreed, but both above not working for IE ?

Comment: They both work for me. What IE version are you using?

Comment: IE: 10.0.9200 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [screen.availwidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.screen) property seems to work ok, but as alternative you can use [document.body.clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.clientWidth). To remove the element you can use `r1.parentNode.removeChild(r1);` [instead of the .remove() method](http://css.dzone.com/articles/removing-element-plain), but for your purpose I'd recommend you rather to adjust the display property here:

```js
window.onload = window.onresize = function () {
    var r1 = document.getElementById("pad1");
    var r2 = document.getElementById("pad2");
    r2.style.display = (document.body.clientWidth <= 1345) ? 'none' : 'list-item';
    r1.style.display = (document.body.clientWidth <= 1255) ? 'none' : 'list-item';
}
```

jsfiddle: [code](http://jsfiddle.net/UrvTu/2/) + [fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/UrvTu/2/show)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are after measuring the client width of the document (the available useful space to work with). Then you can use:

```
document.documentElement.clientWidth
```

You can find more information about this topic here:

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow